# How does browser handle inline javascript events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to pass event object and event origin object to handling function. I believe I understand how **external JavaScript** works:

```
<input id="input2"/>
<script>
function getKey2(e) { alert(this.id+e.keyCode); }
document.getElementById("input2").onkeypress = getKey2;
</script>
```

The `onkeypress` method is defined on input2 DOM, so *this* points to it and event object is passed as the first argument to the function, but I am confused with **inline JavaScript**:

```
<input id="input1" onkeypress="getKey1(this,event)"/>
<script>
function getKey1(obj,e) {
    alert(obj.id+e.keyCode);
}
</script>
```

The first argument, *this*, should be *Window* object, but when it is copied to *obj* on the event, it is event origin object, the *input1* from DOM. The second argument, *event*, should be global event object, but when called, event object is passed to the function. Apparently, my deduction is wrong - how does the call work?

Long story short: why the object values in the following chars are not the same?

```
              | name   object value
----------------------------------
in onkeypress | this   Window
in getKey1    | obj    DOM input1


              | name   object value
----------------------------------
in onkeypress | event  global event
in getKey1    | e      keypress event
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxH2G/)

Comment: Because browsers can bind the correct values?

Comment: @DaveNewton sarcasm? I know this is the very basics of Javascript, but do browsers bind any other values? Is there any standard describing it?

Comment: It's not sarcasm, it's how it works. You're setting an event handler on a specific DOM element. It's a string, there's no reason `this` and `event` wouldn't be bound correctly. It's not being *executed* when the DOM is parsed.

Comment: @DaveNewton that makes a sense. However, HOW it is parsed? Is there anything else bound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C DOM specification states two bindings for inline events:

1. `this` is bound to the element *upon which the inline event was defined*;
2. A local variable with the name `event` is introduced. (IE doesn't do this but the same syntax works for inline event because `event` will be treated as `window.event` in IE.)

In HTML5 the information is buried under [6.1.6.1 Event handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes). The two parts are spread out:

> When an event handler content attribute is set [that is, when an inline event is set] .. Let body [of the synthesized function declaration] be the event handler content attribute's new value .. *Let the function have a single argument called event*. [Note that `onerror` is a special.]
>
> ..
> *Let Scope [or `this`] be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(the element's object, Scope).* [This is chained with other environment contexts such as the Form (if it exists) and the Global Context.]

Comment: Can you please add a link to the relevant part of W3C DOM specification? I can't find it.

Comment: @JanTuroň Updated. It took me a bit to extract from the HTML5 spec. It was much more tersely worded in the older HTML4 spec. Even got a chance to fix my knowledge ..

Comment: It seems to be a correct answer. Just give me a while to study the link before accepting it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for linking to the HTML5.1 spec? I ask, because the same phrasing is already in the older HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 1):

no, this will be the dom object on which the event was triggered, in this case the `<input>` were the onkeyup attribute was set and where the browser will find a handler.

We are going to play a little more with those events: http://jsfiddle.net/nFfEp/

For better understanding about the event triggering and handling this is a very useful document: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow