# how to directly show a hyperlink photo in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a photo that using hyperlink, and there have a onclick function.
When I click the text, it will pop out a div.

Now, I want to directly show the photo on the poped out div instead of go to a another website to see the photo, what should I do? Do I need to change the CSS setting of the pop out div "myModal"?

here is my HTML code

```
 <div class="navbar">
      <a
        onclick="myFunction()"
        href="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/52677035304_b82948dc84_h.jpg"
        >Photo1</a
      >
    </div>
```

js code

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myModal");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

modal in HTML

```
    <div style="text-align: center" id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!--Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="myFunction()" id="cross" class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I want:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to display a modal? That's quite a broad question

Comment: I can display a modal, but now I have also added a hyperlink which is a photo into my clickable text. What I want is to show the hyperlinked photo in the modal.

Comment: Without seeing how the modal is constructed, this would be very difficult to answer correctly

Comment: What should happen to the _"some text"_? Should it be replaced? What else uses this modal? Would other uses expect the text to be present instead of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pass the event object to `myFunction` so that `preventDefault()` can be called to prevent navigating away from the current page. Note, however, that is recommended to use `addEventListener` instead of inline event handlers.
- Add an `<img>` element inside the modal and change its `src` when displaying the image.

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" href="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/52677035304_b82948dc84_h.jpg">Photo1</a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; display: none;" id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span onclick="myFunction()" id="cross" class="close">&times;</span>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = document.getElementById("myModal");
  x.querySelector('img').src = e.target.href;
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should [avoid inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) for multiple reasons. In this case we rely on [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) (`event` for short), which is even _deprecated_.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I mentioned that `addEventListener` is preferred in the answer. Also, no, this is not `window.event`. The context in which inline event handlers are called has the `event` object.

Comment: Even though you mentioned `addEventListener`, most people will only look at the code. Showing the correct example will help others.

Comment: @OskarGrosser No, the event binding is part of the specification and does not rely on `window.event` (which need not be defined for this to work). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430631/9513184

Comment: @Unmitigated The quotes in that answer seem a bit outdated, but **you were completely right**. `event` is a parameter of an anonymous function and therefore not the property `window.event`.